# Asserting that a callback has been passed with the correct scope

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm trying to find a way to test that ObjectA is correctly setting up a callback from ObjectB to ObjectC.

e.g.

```
// In class (has scope issue)
this._processor.process('stuff', this._handler.handle); 

// In test
expect(processor.process).toHaveBeenCalledWith('stuff', handler.handle);
```

What I went to test is that the following call actually takes place:

```
this._processor.process('stuff', this._handler.handle.bind(this._handler));
```

I'm aware I can fix this by handling the callback like so:

```
this._processor.process('stuff', function() {
    this._handler.handle()
});
```

And testing that the 'handler' spy gets called on callback from the process function (this is how I'm generally doing things at the moment). But setting it all up makes the test messy and adds code and complexity to the class under test purely to make it testable.

Answer (score 1):

In the general sense, each call to a spy tracks the scope in the `object` property (assuming Jasmine 1.3):

```
it("has the right scope", function () {
    var scopeObj = {foo: "bar"};
    var spy = jasmine.createSpy("scope");

    spy.call(scopeObj, 42, "blue");

    // Also can use spy.calls[0].object
    expect(spy.mostRecentCall.object).toBe(scopeObj);
});
```

Comment: Jasmine 2.0 still has the `object` property as well. The expectation would just change to `expect(spy.calls.mostRecent().object).toBe(scopeObj);`